# C, determining stack usage of third party functions

Tags: multithreading, function, gcc, posix, stack-overflow

Not exactly an uncommon sort of question, but not a question I have yet to find an adequate answer to.

Basically, I am trying to work out how to calculate required stacks sizes in new threads in a threaded program I intend to write.

As I see, I need to determine how much stack each function I call uses, then work the possible functions call chains to determine correct stack size.

Now, with the functions I write myself, I can see I just work out what each function will at most put onto a stack when called using the variables it uses.

However, what I can't be so sure of is what third party functions (such as glibc functions) will use in terms of stack space. I also decided monitoring their stack usage is not an acceptable approach because I can't be sure I analysed everything that may effect a third party functions stack usage, I also cannot be sure newer versions of a function may not use more stack space than I required.

So what I need is a way of finding exactly how much stack space any third party functions may use.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use a 64-bit platform, you can pretty much ignore this. You can give each thread a absurdly large stack space with no issues.

Comment: Is your question of a practical nature? Are you facing a specific problem?

Comment: Yeah - are you on embedded with limited RAM, or what?

Comment: Well, firstly, I am currently planning how I am going todo an application. I am not on embedded, but I am likely to compile my app onto something like a raspberry PI. Generally, I wish to be as precise as possible to get out as much from my app as possible.

Answer (score 0):

In general this is only possible when the source code for the third party function is known. There are tools that can analyze the maximum required stackspace for each function and detect recursive calls. One such tool I have used at work is Gimpel's FlexeLint (Unix) == PClint (Windows).

Comment: Note that gcc can also give you the stack space for individual functions it compiles with the -fstack-usage option